# How to spot corp thieves?

Tags: eve-online

EVE Online is a game where all kinds of scams take place, and most of them are within the rules of the game. Corp thieves are a particular danger once a corporation amasses significant assets. The corporation I'm a member of (but not a director) was robbed very recently, and I'd like some suggestions on how to prevent this from reoccurring.

What kind of background checks are useful to spot corp thieves? Are there any particular warning signs one should pay attention to?

Answer (score 2):

1) Asking for information that they don't need: Spy's are out to sell your intel, but most are pretty bad at it. Check corp histories. If they are asking for your POS location before even making it in the door, you may have a problem.

2) Asking for access they don't need: Thieves need access, and are often too lazy to work for it. Many will simply ask for access.

3) Leave thief bate. I leave about 50 million worth of ships in the corp area that anyone can access it. If they want to burn themselves on such a low amount, awesome.

4) Look for Red flags: The player is a 2 week old noob, but has their API key in EVEHQ? Might want to keep an eye on them. "New" characters are great because they are nothing to burn. Make sure that noob really is and not some 3 year old player.

5) Prepare for the inevitability: Never put all your eggs in one basket. Don't hold more as a corp then you are prepared to lose, eventually a thief will try for it. Plan ahead, and be ready.

Comment: 6) Search forums if this character was sold recently. 7) look at evewho.com

Answer (score 1):

Grab a thing called EVEmon (if i remember it correctly). You ask the person to give you their API Key, shove it into the EVEmon, and you can see all their characters on that account and the age/skills of the characters (so you know that he isnt working for some other corp and just made a basic character just to enter your corp and steal your $h!7)

Otherwise, you can check his Corp membership history. Has he dropped out of plenty of corps the last three days? HAH.

I haven't played EVE in a while, but ta's all the stuff i've learned after a year of shock trooper service.